# react render component based on server data

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So I have a number of components imported to my main component:

```
import ServerCreator            from   './ServerCreator'
import RouterCreator            from   './RouterCreator'
import VolumeCreator            from   './VolumeCreator'
```

and based on data that is received by an ajax call I would like to render one of these with a number of props.
The data will be something like this:

```
data = {
displayName :"Server",
icon: "microchip"
createName: 'ServerCreator',
...
},
```

is there anyway I could do so?

```
const Component = React.createElement(data.createName,{...props},null)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you facing any error?

Comment: what is `data.createName` returning? Can you please the code related to `data.createName`

Comment: it thinks im rendering an html tag instead of a component because I'm sending a string to react.createelement

Comment: data is the received data from server : (response.data actually)

Comment: @AmirShahbabaie you can only pass the data as props. Not as the first argument. Check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass string component names to `React.createElement` instead you need to pass component reference.

What you need to do is to maintain a map for your Component in the main.js file like

```
import ServerCreator            from   './ServerCreator'
import RouterCreator            from   './RouterCreator'
import VolumeCreator            from   './VolumeCreator'

const map = {
    'ServerCreator': ServerCreator,
    'RouterCreator': RouterCreator,
    'VolumeCreator': VolumeCreator,
}
```

and then while rendering you need to resolve the component from map and render it using JSX directly

```
render() {
     ...
   const Component = map[data.createName];
   return <Component {...props} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React.createElement expects to receive an element as first argument, such as `div`, `section`, `span`. Make sure the first argument is an element.

```js
React.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

E.g.

```js
let welcome = React.createElement(
  "section",
  { style: { color: "red" } },
  `Welcome to react world`
);

ReactDOM.render(welcome, document.querySelector("#root"));
```